# Toshiba Netbook works on LiveUSB, but not when installed

Tags: 11.10, installation, drivers, hardware

When running Ubuntu 11.10 live on my USB, everything works perfectly. Once I install the OS, however, most of the hardware is no longer recognized.

Once I booted into Ubuntu, I had a number of problems:

- The touchpad doesn't work.
- The USB mouse is detected only after unplugging it and plugging it back in.
- Wireless network not detected; Network Manager doesn't provide the option to "connect to wireless network"
- When an Ethernet cable is plugged in, the connection is detected, but automatic connection fails.
- No sound output.

My Toshiba Netbook has a 120GB HDD, 1GB RAM, and Windows XP installed. After installing Ubuntu, some partitions were created:

```
sda1: 100GB: working XP
sda2: ~18GB: / 
sda3: ~500Mb /boot 
sda4: ~2Gb swap
```

All my hardware information from `lshw`:

```
desuna-toshiba-nb100
    description: Notebook
    version: PLL10E-00K01YG3
    width: 32 bits
    capabilities: smbios-2.4 dmi-2.4
    configuration: boot=normal chassis=notebook family=Intel_Mobile sku=BasicNB_QS uuid=ED62DDB0-A1CD-11DD-A70E-001E337691EB
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       product: Portable PC
       vendor: TOSHIBA
       physical id: 0
       version: Base Board Version
       serial: Base Board Serial Number
       slot: Base Board Chassis Location
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: INSYDE
          physical id: 0
          version: 1.10
          date: 09/15/2008
          size: 1MiB
          capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppynec int13floppytoshiba int13floppy360 int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int9keyboard int10video acpi usb
     *-memory
          description: System Memory
          physical id: 15
          slot: System board or motherboard
          size: 1GiB
          capacity: 1GiB
        *-bank
             description: DIMM DDR2 Synchronous 533 MHz (1.9 ns)
             product: HYMP112S64CP6-S6
             vendor: Hynix Semiconductor (Hyundai Electronics)
             physical id: 0
             serial: 0x00002123
             slot: J2
             size: 1GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 533MHz (1.9ns)
     *-cpu
          description: CPU
          product: Intel(R) Atom(TM) CPU N270   @ 1.60GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: 1a
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: 6.12.2
          serial: 0001-06C2-0000-0000-0000-0000
          slot: CPU
          size: 800MHz
          capacity: 1600MHz
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 533MHz
          capabilities: fpu fpu_exception wp vme de tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic mtrr pge mca cmov pat clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl est tm2 ssse3 xtpr pdcm movbe lahf_lm cpufreq
          configuration: id=0
        *-cache:0
             description: L2 cache
             physical id: 1b
             slot: Unknown
             size: 512KiB
             capacity: 512KiB
             capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
        *-cache:1
             description: L1 cache
             physical id: 1c
             slot: Unknown
             size: 32KiB
             capacity: 32KiB
             capabilities: synchronous internal write-back instruction
        *-logicalcpu:0
             description: Logical CPU
             physical id: 0.1
             width: 32 bits
             capabilities: logical
        *-logicalcpu:1
             description: Logical CPU
             physical id: 0.2
             width: 32 bits
             capabilities: logical
     *-pci
          description: Host bridge
          product: Mobile 945GME Express Memory Controller Hub
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 03
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
          configuration: driver=agpgart-intel
          resources: irq:0
        *-display:0
             description: VGA compatible controller
             product: Mobile 945GME Express Integrated Graphics Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
             version: 03
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
             configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
             resources: irq:17 memory:54280000-542fffff ioport:40f0(size=8) memory:40000000-4fffffff memory:54300000-5433ffff
        *-display:1 UNCLAIMED
             description: Display controller
             product: Mobile 945GM/GMS/GME, 943/940GML Express Integrated Graphics Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 2.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.1
             version: 03
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: memory:54200000-5427ffff
        *-multimedia UNCLAIMED
             description: Audio device
             product: N10/ICH 7 Family High Definition Audio Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1b
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
             version: 02
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: memory:d0000000-d0003fff
        *-pci:0
             description: PCI bridge
             product: N10/ICH 7 Family PCI Express Port 1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.0
             version: 02
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:40 ioport:2000(size=8192) memory:53200000-541fffff ioport:50000000(size=17825792)
           *-network
                description: Ethernet interface
                product: RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
                vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
                logical name: eth0
                version: 02
                serial: 00:1e:33:76:91:eb
                size: 10Mbit/s
                capacity: 100Mbit/s
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
                configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
                resources: irq:42 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:50010000-50010fff memory:50000000-5000ffff memory:50020000-5003ffff
        *-pci:1
             description: PCI bridge
             product: N10/ICH 7 Family PCI Express Port 2
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.1
             version: 02
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:41 ioport:1000(size=4096) memory:52100000-531fffff ioport:51100000(size=16777216)
           *-network UNCLAIMED
                description: Ethernet controller
                product: AR242x / AR542x Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express)
                vendor: Atheros Communications Inc.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
                version: 01
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list
                configuration: latency=0
                resources: memory:52100000-5210ffff
        *-usb:0
             description: USB Controller
             product: N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1d
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.0
             version: 02
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: uhci bus_master
             configuration: driver=uhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:21 ioport:40a0(size=32)
        *-usb:1
             description: USB Controller
             product: N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #2
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1d.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.1
             version: 02
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: uhci bus_master
             configuration: driver=uhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:22 ioport:4080(size=32)
        *-usb:2
             description: USB Controller
             product: N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #3
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1d.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.2
             version: 02
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: uhci bus_master
             configuration: driver=uhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:20 ioport:4060(size=32)
        *-usb:3
             description: USB Controller
             product: N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #4
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1d.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.3
             version: 02
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: uhci bus_master
             configuration: driver=uhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:23 ioport:4040(size=32)
        *-usb:4
             description: USB Controller
             product: N10/ICH 7 Family USB2 EHCI Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1d.7
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.7
             version: 02
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ehci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:21 memory:54344400-543447ff
        *-pci:2
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1e
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1e.0
             version: e2
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci subtractive_decode bus_master cap_list
        *-isa
             description: ISA bridge
             product: 82801GBM (ICH7-M) LPC Interface Bridge
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.0
             version: 02
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: isa bus_master cap_list
             configuration: latency=0
        *-ide
             description: IDE interface
             product: 82801G (ICH7 Family) IDE Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.1
             version: 02
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: ide bus_master
             configuration: driver=ata_piix latency=0
             resources: irq:11 ioport:1f0(size=8) ioport:3f6 ioport:170(size=8) ioport:376 ioport:40c0(size=16)
        *-storage
             description: SATA controller
             product: 82801GBM/GHM (ICH7 Family) SATA AHCI Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
             logical name: scsi2
             version: 02
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: storage msi pm ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list emulated
             configuration: driver=ahci latency=0
             resources: irq:43 ioport:40d8(size=8) ioport:40fc(size=4) ioport:40d0(size=8) ioport:40f8(size=4) ioport:4020(size=16) memory:54344000-543443ff
           *-disk
                description: ATA Disk
                product: TOSHIBA MK1252GS
                vendor: Toshiba
                physical id: 0.0.0
                bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0
                logical name: /dev/sda
                version: LV01
                serial: 88N1C3BIT
                size: 111GiB (120GB)
                capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
                configuration: ansiversion=5 signature=442774ea
              *-volume:0
                   description: Windows NTFS volume
                   physical id: 1
                   bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0,1
                   logical name: /dev/sda1
                   logical name: /media/2C5476055475D1D6
                   version: 3.1
                   serial: a67d70c4-3fa9-2e41-9d54-9f36cf5d38b5
                   size: 93GiB
                   capacity: 93GiB
                   capabilities: primary bootable ntfs initialized
                   configuration: clustersize=4096 created=2008-09-25 01:47:00 filesystem=ntfs modified_by_chkdsk=true mount.fstype=fuseblk mount.options=rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096 mounted_on_nt4=true resize_log_file=true state=mounted upgrade_on_mount=true
              *-volume:1
                   description: Extended partition
                   physical id: 2
                   bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0,2
                   logical name: /dev/sda2
                   size: 1907MiB
                   capacity: 1907MiB
                   capabilities: primary extended partitioned partitioned:extended
                 *-logicalvolume
                      description: Linux swap / Solaris partition
                      physical id: 5
                      logical name: /dev/sda5
                      capacity: 1907MiB
                      capabilities: nofs
              *-volume:2
                   description: EXT4 volume
                   vendor: Linux
                   physical id: 3
                   bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0,3
                   logical name: /dev/sda3
                   logical name: /boot
                   version: 1.0
                   serial: b7d7bfa6-ef74-4dd4-b451-cd4322ce0f8a
                   size: 477MiB
                   capacity: 477MiB
                   capabilities: primary journaled extended_attributes huge_files dir_nlink recover extents ext4 ext2 initialized
                   configuration: created=2012-04-15 21:56:27 filesystem=ext4 lastmountpoint=/boot modified=2012-04-16 07:11:26 mount.fstype=ext4 mount.options=rw,relatime,user_xattr,acl,barrier=1,data=ordered mounted=2012-04-16 07:11:26 state=mounted
              *-volume:3
                   description: EXT4 volume
                   vendor: Linux
                   physical id: 4
                   bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0,4
                   logical name: /dev/sda4
                   logical name: /
                   version: 1.0
                   serial: 8651c2cb-2331-4e4b-a149-933f101169ac
                   size: 16GiB
                   capacity: 16GiB
                   capabilities: primary journaled extended_attributes large_files huge_files dir_nlink recover extents ext4 ext2 initialized
                   configuration: created=2012-04-15 21:56:55 filesystem=ext4 lastmountpoint=/ modified=2012-04-15 22:23:54 mount.fstype=ext4 mount.options=rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,user_xattr,acl,barrier=1,data=ordered mounted=2012-04-16 07:11:26 state=mounted
        *-serial UNCLAIMED
             description: SMBus
             product: N10/ICH 7 Family SMBus Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
             version: 02
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: ioport:4000(size=32)
     *-scsi:0
          physical id: 1
          bus info: usb@1:8
          logical name: scsi6
          capabilities: emulated scsi-host
          configuration: driver=usb-storage
        *-disk
             description: SCSI Disk
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@6:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/sdb
     *-scsi:1
          physical id: 2
          bus info: usb@1:3
          logical name: scsi7
          capabilities: emulated scsi-host
          configuration: driver=usb-storage
        *-disk
             description: SCSI Disk
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@7:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/sdc
             size: 7509MiB (7873MB)
             capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
             configuration: signature=0005d459
           *-volume
                description: Windows FAT volume
                vendor: mkdosfs
                physical id: 1
                bus info: scsi@7:0.0.0,1
                logical name: /dev/sdc1
                logical name: /media/963B-DA32
                version: FAT32
                serial: 963b-da32
                size: 7503MiB
                capacity: 7503MiB
                capabilities: primary bootable fat initialized
                configuration: FATs=2 filesystem=fat mount.fstype=vfat mount.options=rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,fmask=0022,dmask=0077,codepage=cp437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,showexec,utf8,flush,errors=remount-ro state=mounted
```

**In short, everything works fine with a LiveUSB, but after installation, none of the hardware works. How do I fix this?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Ubuntu 10.04 LTS solves all the problems and works like a charm.